# La manera correcta de capturar echo json_encode() en jquery

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Estoy intentando capturar la variable json_encode a través de jquery, pero sin ningún resultado.

Ademas de capturar dicho resultado de un archivo php, el mismo debe ser incorporado en una tabla de una pagina, es simplemente mostrar un query en una pagina php, que a su vez esta dentro de otra pagina construct en php, espero haberme explicado bien.

Este es mi código del query mysql en php **riepilogo-loop.php**:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include '../../utente/index.php';
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pasword", "database");
if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

$result_array = array();

$query = "SELECT usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, note, stato FROM spesa WHERE usuario = '".$username ."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $item_array = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($result_array, $row);
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result_array);
    $link->close();
```

como resultado de **`echo json_encode($result_array);`** tengo esto:

```
[{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"16\/03\/2020","codice":"302","articolo":"Cacio Molisano Bianco Stagionato Kg. 1,5","quantita":"1","note":"TEST","stato":"CONFERMATA"},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"208","articolo":"Ciambelle pass. kg 3","quantita":"3","note":"Confermata","stato":""},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"208","articolo":"Ciambelle pass. kg 3","quantita":"3","note":"Confermata","stato":""},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"101","articolo":"Stracchino gr 100","quantita":"2","note":"ADMINISTRATOR","stato":"Confermata"},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"613","articolo":"Trofie 500 gr","quantita":"1","note":"Trofie de 500 gr","stato":"Confermata"}][{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"16\/03\/2020","codice":"302","articolo":"Cacio Molisano Bianco Stagionato Kg. 1,5","quantita":"1","note":"TEST","stato":"CONFERMATA"},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"208","articolo":"Ciambelle pass. kg 3","quantita":"3","note":"Confermata","stato":""},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"208","articolo":"Ciambelle pass. kg 3","quantita":"3","note":"Confermata","stato":""},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"101","articolo":"Stracchino gr 100","quantita":"2","note":"ADMINISTRATOR","stato":"Confermata"},{"usuario":"Valter Lafratta","fecha":"17\/03\/2020","codice":"613","articolo":"Trofie 500 gr","quantita":"1","note":"Trofie de 500 gr","stato":"Confermata"}]
```

Ahora bien, para capturar e insertar estos resultados en otra pagina tengo este código **riepilogo.php**:

```
<?php
    $content = "
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-xs-12'>
                <div class='box'>
                  <div class='box-header'>
                    <h3 class='box-title'>Le tue spese</h3>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-header -->
                  <div class='box-body'>
                    <table id='spesa' class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Dipendente</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Codice Prodotto</th>
                        <th>Descrizione Prodotto</th>
                        <th>Quantità</th>
                        <th>Stato</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>

                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <p><a href='create.php'>Nuova Spesa</a></p>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
              </div>
            </div>";

include('index.php');
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/config/riepilogo-loop.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var usuario = response[i].usuario;
                var fecha = response[i].fecha;
                var codice = response[i].codice;
                var articolo = response[i].articolo;
                var quantita = response[i].quantita;
                var stato = response[i].stato;
                var note = response[i].note;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + usuario + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + fecha + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + codice + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + articolo + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + quantita + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + stato + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + note + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#spesa tbody").append(tr_str);
            } 

        }
    });
});
 </script>
```

La variable **`$content`** es parte de index.php, index es el archivo receptor/construct.
No obtengo resultados de la ejecución del código, solo muestra los cabezales de las columnas, sin ningún tipo de data insertada, lo que me tiene un poco desconcertado es el hecho de que hay data, en todos los ejemplo que he visto, el script de jquery esta bien, pero sigo sin obtener los resultados.

**UPDATE**

Del archivo php que genera el mysql query y envia el paquete JSON, se elimino el siguiente codigo:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

array_push($result_array, $row);
```

Se agrego la siguiente linea :

```
$result_array[]=$row;
```

Con este cambio en el archivo PHP, se envia un string JSON correcto.

Estaría muy agradecido si me pueden indicar en donde esta el error o si el código que estoy implementando esta errado.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda recibida, comentarios y/o sugerencias serán bien recibidas.

Valter.

**UPDATE 2**

riepilogo-loop.php:

```
<?php   

include '../../utente/index.php';
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", password, "database");
$result_array = array();

$query = "SELECT usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, note, stato FROM spesa WHERE usuario = '".$username ."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $item_array = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result_array[]=$row;

    }
}
    echo json_encode($result_array);
    $link->close();

?>
```

Riepilogo.php

```
<?php
    $content = "
                <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-xs-12'>
                <div class='box'>
                  <div class='box-header'>
                    <h3 class='box-title'>Le tue spese</h3>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-header -->
                  <div class='box-body'>
                    <table id='spesa' class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Dipendente</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Codice Prodotto</th>
                        <th>Descrizione Prodotto</th>
                        <th>Quantità</th>
                        <th>Stato</th>
                        <th>Note</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>

                      </tfoot>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.box-body -->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>
                        <p><a href='create.php'>Nuova Spesa</a></p>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
              </div>
            </div>";

include('index.php');
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/config/riepilogo-loop.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            var len = response.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var usuario = response[i].usuario;
                var fecha = response[i].fecha;
                var codice = response[i].codice;
                var articolo = response[i].articolo;
                var quantita = response[i].quantita;
                var stato = response[i].stato;
                var note = response[i].note;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + usuario + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + fecha + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + codice + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + articolo + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + quantita + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + stato + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + note + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#spesa tbody").append(tr_str);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: El problema es que **tu JSON no es válido**. Puedes copiarlo y [pegarlo aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) para verificar tu JSON, es inválido por la forma en que lo estás construyendo en PHP. `array_push` tiene ese problema. Prueba así sencillamente: **`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result_array[]=$row;
        }`** y debería funcionar. De todos modos revisa el JSON que se produzca usando el enlace de más arriba. Y en el código Ajax no tienes que parsear nada, ya le indicaste en el `dataType` que esperas un JSON y Ajax lo traea ya parseado.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano pruebo e informo, le remuevo tambien el die error de conexion a la base de datos? Gracias

Comment: Cuando esperas un JSON en el cliente, en caso de error puedes crear un `array ("error"=>"Mensaje del error")` así en la respuesta puedes verificar con `if (response.error) {  //hubo error } else { //no hubo error, mostrar los datos}` O sea, dar coherencia al código.

Comment: Deberías quitar también el despliegue de errores que tienes al principio, una vez el código funcione.

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo un json positivo con el cambio en el código, pero sigue sin mostrar resultados en la pagina riepilogo.php Con respecto al array de errores, quede un poco confundido, sugieres de crear el código en el archivo que recibe el json o el que lo genera. Gracias

Comment: ¿Dónde es que no muestra los resultados? Edita la pregunta poniendo al final el código como lo tienes ahora y el JSON que estás recibiendo para verificarlo. Lo del error quizá te lo explico más adelante en una respuesta.

Comment: Bueno actualice el archivo php, ya recibiendo el string json correcto, pero el archivo que recibe el paquete JSON que es el que muestra la data en la tabla, sigue sin generar ningun dato, no muestra resultados, en el console.log me muestra esto: `"parsererror" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Pon al final de la pregunta el PHP correcto como lo tienes ahora para revisarlo. Debe haber algún error de sintaxis en alguna parte. El error indica que está saliendo código html que puede ser algún mensaje de error o algo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para solucionar este inconveniente realice lo siguiente, se creo un archivo config.php en este caso, con la información para acceder a la base de datos, un archivo conexión.

**CONFIG.PHP**

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$host = "localhost";
$user = "User";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "Database name";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
```

Al código le agregue estas dos lineas:

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Al archivo riepilogo-loop.php, le hice varias modificaciones:

**RIEPILOGO-LOOP.PHP**

```
include "config.php";
$return_arr = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM spesa WHERE usuario = '".$username ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $username = $row['usuario'];
    $fecha = $row['fecha'];
    $codice = $row['codice'];
    $articolo = $row['articolo'];
    $quantita = $row['quantita'];
    $stato = $row['stato'];
    $note = $row['note'];
    $return_arr[] = array("usuario" => $username,
                    "fecha" => $fecha,
                    "codice" => $codice,
                    "articolo" => $articolo,
                    "quantita" => $quantita,
                    "stato" => $stato,
                    "note" => $note);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
$con->close();
```

Al archivo le elimine la linea `include "../../utente/index.php";` y esta fue la clave, el resultado de json_encode, deberia ser solo el string JSON, en mi caso venia con el código html del index.php.
El error que me generaba la consulta fue:

> **status code: 200  errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

Al observar el resultado de la solicitud del código en el **tab network** de chrome, pude constatar que con el string del json se le anteponía el html del index.

Gracias a todos por el aporte, todas sus respuestas son validas y asertivas.

Answer (score 3):

La función `json_encode()` de **PHP** convierte el valor dado en un `string` en formato **JSON**. Por lo que al tratarlo como si fuese un objeto en el `success` de la llamada **AJAX**, no vas a poder obtener los valores.

Necesitas primero transformar la respuesta del servidor en un **Objeto**:

**JQuery**

```
$.ajax({
        url: '../api/config/riepilogo-loop.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(response){
            let objeto_JSON = $.parseJSON(response);

           objeto_JSON.forEach(function (elemento) {
                var usuario = elemento.usuario;
                var fecha = elemento.fecha;
                var codice = elemento.codice;
                var articolo = elemento.articolo;
                var quantita = elemento.quantita;
                var stato = elemento.stato;
                var note = elemento.note;

                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + usuario + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + fecha + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + codice + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + articolo + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + quantita + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + stato + "</td>" +
                    "<td align='center'>" + note + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";

                $("#spesa tbody").append(tr_str);
            }); 

        }
    });
```

También sustituí el bucle `for` por el uso de `forEach()` para una mayor comodidad.

**Referencia:** [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, pero sigo sin obtener resultados, la tabla que debe mostrar los resultados sigue estando en blanco.

Comment: ¿Al hacerle un `console.log()` a la variable donde almacenas  `$.parseJSON(response)` obtienes lo que esperas del servidor?

Comment: en blanco, no obtengo ningún resultado en la consola, pero en el archivo **riepilogo-loop.php** si tengo data con `echo json_encode($result_array);`

Comment: Cuando se pone `dataType: 'JSON',` en la petición Ajax no hay que hacer parse, Ajax parsea la respuesta. Por lo tanto esto sobra: `let objeto_JSON = $.parseJSON(response);` Si no funciona es porque el JSON que viene desde el servidor no sería válido. Cuando se espera un JSON desde el servidor no se pueden poner cosas como estas: `die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());` porque en caso de error se imprimiría una cadena en pantalla que dañaría el JSON. Hay que escribir código coherente en el servidor que recoja los errores en un array y los devuelva como json.

Comment: Te tienen que estar saliendo mensajes de error por consola que no estaría de más que nos pusieras. De todas formas si el `console.log()` te sale vacío es muy posible que no estés accediendo a la ruta del `.php` correctamente, en cuyo caso encontrarías un error 404 en consola.

Answer (score 1):

Todo esto lo puedes hacer de una forma simple con `$.getJSON()`. Teniendo en cuenta que esta es tu tabla:

```
<table id='spesa' class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Dipendente</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Codice Prodotto</th>
            <th>Descrizione Prodotto</th>
            <th>Quantità</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
            <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$.getJSON("../api/config/riepilogo-loop.php", function (json) {
    $('#spesa').append("<tbody>");
    for (var counter = 0; counter < json.length; counter++) {
        $('#spesa').append("<tr><td>" + json[counter].usuario + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + json[counter].fecha + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + json[counter].codice + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + json[counter].articolo + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + json[counter].quantita + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + json[counter].stato + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + json[counter].none + "</td></tr>");
    }
    $('#spesa').append("</tbody>");
});
```

Como la tabla la puse sin un **tbody** entonces lo primero que hago al recibir el **json** es agregarle dicho **tbody** y después hago un ciclo **for** que sea menos a la longitud del **json** y le hago un `append()` a el body de la tabla de todos los datos, posteriormente agrego el cierre del **tbody** y listo, con esto ya deberías de tener tu tabla funcionando sin problemas. `$.getJSON()` requiere que desde **PHP** conviertas el arreglo con `echo json_encode($tuarreglo);`.

Comment: Gracias @Eduardo por tu aporte, pero sigo sin poder mostrar el resultado en la pagina, me sigue apareciendo en blanco con solo los cabezales de la columnas. Cree un archivo test con el mismo codigo que tu sugieres e incluuyo el `echo json_encode($result_array);` si muestra el string json con los resultados del query, pero tambien muestra en blanco la data, solo los cabezales de las columnas.

Comment: De hecho te debería de funcionar sin problema alguno, alguna acción estas haciendo mal, porque si muestra el json como mencionas al recibirlo en el getjson debe funcionar sin problemas. ¿Ya probaste hacer un console.log(json); dentro del getjson para ver que llegue hay tu json sin problemas?.

Comment: no obtengo ningun resultado con el console, en blanco. `$.getJSON("riepilogo-loop.php", function (json) { console.log(json);`

Comment: Pues entonces todos tus errores vienen desde tu php, porque si al json no llega nada entonces tu problema esta en tu php no en tu javascript.

Comment: pero si fueran errores de php, no generaría el query y no mostraría el string, no se es mi percepción

Comment: Pues entonces deberías ver si estas mandando a llamar correctamente a la url del json, porque si no te sale nada en console.log es porque no está llegando hay la información. Trata utilizando la url absoluta con http y todo de tu local o tu sitio.

Comment: Pues nada, todo en blanco, sin registros en la consola, pero el echo json_encode($result_array); sigue generando data, pero simplemente no se muestra en riepilogo.php

Comment: Creo que aqui ya es problema tuyo, porque las respuestas ya te las dieron. Si si te imprime el json encode y en console log no te da nada, entonces en el intermedio de esas 2 es donde no haces algo bien. No estas poniendo bien el archivo que regresa la informacion.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente hay que ser consciente del contexto en el que te estás moviendo: una **comunicación entre cliente y servidor** en la que el cliente manda algo y **espera del servidor una respuesta** que en este caso debe ser un JSON (porque así lo indicaste en `dataType`).

Eso significa una cosa muy sencilla: **pase lo que pase en el servidor, éste tiene que mandar una respuesta del tipo indicado (que es JSON en este caso), eso y nada más que eso**. Y para hacerlo, tienes que dar **coherencia** a tu código en dos aspectos:

1. Controlando **todas las eventualidades** en el código al que envías la petición mediante el parámetro `url` de Ajax. Significa que en ese código debes asegurar que no salga por pantalla nada, absolutamente nada distinto de lo que pides, que para este caso es un JSON.
2. Un error que se escapa mucho, sobre todo cuando se trabaja con Ajax, es pensar que podemos usar en la petición Ajax (en el parámetro `url`) archivos que usamos para otros fines, como archivos del tipo `index.html` o archivos con formularios, etc. Eso no es posible, **no se pueden mezclar las cosas, en el parámetro `url` de la petición no debes poner archivos que usas para otras cosas**. Si ese archivo por ejemplo tiene salida por pantalla, cuando la petición tenga éxito traerá al cliente **todo el contenido de ese archivo**. Si lo que esperas en un JSON o un XML eso provocará un objeto no válido. Si lo que esperas es un HTML, estarás trayendo el contenido de un archivo que no nesitas realmente.

   En resumen: el archivo que se pone como parámetro en la petición Ajax, debe ser un archivo **utilitario**, que controle las salidad y que sirva únicamente para el transporte de datos entre el cliente y el servidor. Eso no significa que no puedas reutilizar. Tú puedes tener un archivo que gestione peticiones desde muchos puntos (por ejemplo un CRUD), pero con un estricto control del flujo de salida.

   Eso incluye, nunca mejor dicho, a los archivos que son incluidos. Por ejemplo, no debes incluir en el flujo archivos que hagan `echo, die, print`... o con bloques HTML. Por lo mismo, porque todo ese contenido vendrá con la petición, dañando el JSON, el XML o trayendo código HTML basura que se mostrará en el cliente.

   Me extendí un poco en ese punto porque he visto en muchas preguntas que esto no queda claro, sobre todo cuando se empieza con Ajax. Es **fundamental tener claros esos dos conceptos**, de lo contrario irás de bruces con Ajax, desperdiciando una de las herramientas más potentes que existe hoy día en la programación web.

Entendido eso, pasamos a cubrir esas deficiencias en tu código. Necesitas establecer en el servidor un **control total del flujo de salida**, particularmente importante para casos en los que trabajas con respuestas como JSON, XML u otras.

Tu código **no es coherente** porque deja escapar **varias** situaciones que pueden ser imprevisibles: si no hay conexión no hace nada (antes tenías un `die` que rompía la coherencia), si la consulta falla no hace nada, si no hay filas no hace nada.

Todo eso debe controlarse. Una forma de hacerlo es recogiendo mensajes con la clave `error` en un array, que luego puedes usar en el cliente para saber si hubo error o si trae datos.

**OJO** esos errores que se controlan ahí son por decirlo de alguna manera errores de *lógica*. Hay otro tipo de errores (de red, de servidor) que se controlan con la función `error` propia de Ajax y que deberías implementar cuando todo funcione, porque es la única forma de controlar errores que escapan al ámbito del código.

Por ejemplo:

### PHP

```
<?php   
    include '../../utente/index.php';
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", password, "database");
    $result_array = array();
    if ($link) {
        $query = "SELECT usuario, fecha, codice, articolo, quantita, note, stato FROM spesa WHERE usuario = '".$username ."'";

        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {     
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $result_array[]=$row;
                }
            }else{
                $result_array["error"]="No se encontraron filas";       
            }

        }else{
            $result_array["error"]="La consulta es errónea";        
        }   
        $link->close();
    }else{
        $result_array["error"]="No hay conexión";       
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($result_array);
?>
```

---

### Javascript

Como ya dije, si pones esto `dataType: 'JSON'` no necesitas hacer un parseo (hacerlo daría más bien error), pues ya Ajax hará el parseo.

Para completar la coherencia con lo que escribiste en el servidor, sólo hay que hacer esto:

```
    success: function(response){
         if (response.error) {
            //Hay mensajes con la clave error, mostrarlos o hacer otra cosa
         }else{
            //Hay datos, leerlos
         }
```

Con eso el código debe funcionar. O decir lo que ha causado su no funcionamiento. Puedes depurar con `console.log` o de otro modo.

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, déjame verificar y aviso.

Comment: Pues nada, todo en blanco, sin registros en la consola, pero el `echo json_encode($result_array); ` sigue generando data, pero simplemente no se muestra en riepilogo.php

Comment: ¿Qué datos muestra @Valter? Haz un `console.log(response);` en el `success`

Comment: ejecute el archivo riepilogo-loop.php directamente en el browser, le retire la linea del codigo: `include'../../utente/index.php`  y genero este error {"error":"No se encontraron filas"}

Comment: ¿Y dejándole ese archivo qué arroja?

Comment: nada, el index seria el construct de la pagina, el index mantiene la sesion iniciada y permite que el query tenga la condicion de filtrar los usuarios en la base de datos. where usuario = $username

Comment: @Valter No entiendo mucho. El usuario lo filtras vía Ajax ¿no? con esa consulta que haces a la base de datos. ¿Acaso usas ese archivo PHP para otra cosa también?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105736/discussion-between-valter-and-a-cedano).